# slidify - how to position an image?

Tags: r, slidify

I'm experimenting with using  [slidify](http://slidify.org/) for making html5 presentations. While the use of markdown for creating bullets and text is clear, I'm unsure how to work with images. I can resize and such using [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), but how do I center (or flush top/right/bottom) and image using markdown?

EDIT

I'm referring generally to images here, but this also applies to R graphics. The default appears to be centering images - I'd like to be able to place them side-by-side, or even in arbitrary locations.

Comment: I'm working through this same problem right now. I would have thought that `fig.align='center'` would have done the trick, but it doesn't appear to...or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I think you'll have to use html to do this.  You can do a few things 1) contact Ramnath directly through [slidify's GitHub](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues?page=1&state=open) and ask (he's very open to feedback) 2) using the [github version](https://github.com/trinker/reports) of the reports package with slidify you can add images with some control using `IM` (which really just produces the html for images).  I think (though can not speak for Ramnath) slidify is intended to utilize Markdown as much as possible and where not use the HTML.

Comment: I just realized you mean R produced graphics.  You could still do as I said but grab the graphics from the cache.  Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: Can you post a link to your Rmd file and your html file?

Comment: Hi Ramnath, link to my example .Rmd and .html is published on https://github.com/johnstantongeddes/JSGtest ('publish' to github being one of the features of slidify I really appreciate btw). I've made an edit to the question. I realize know that the likely answer is that I can change position using the .html output, but this would be wiped out with each 'knit'. Would it require a new template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an (ugly) work-around to center and resize images to make sure they all fit on your slides.

Add the following to the top of your `index.Rmd`, just below the description block.

```
<!-- Limit image width and height -->
<style type='text/css'>
img {
    max-height: 560px;
    max-width: 964px;
}
</style>

<!-- Center image on slide -->
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
    $("p:has(img)").addClass('centered');
});
</script>
```

The CSS will limit the height of images to avoid having them overflow.

The JS will load jQuery and then find all paragraph elements which contain an `<img>` element, and add the `.centered` class, which sets `text-align: center`.

The same version of jQuery is loaded later on by Slidify, but I couldn't find a straight-forward way to load the `<script>` block after Slidify has loaded jQuery.

Alternatively, you could also manually achieve this using plain HTML:

```
<div style='text-align: center;'>
    <img height='560' src='x.png' />
</div>
```

However, you would need to do this for each image.